# Custom create schema in Azure mobile service

Tags: azure, azure-mobile-services

Scenario: I have a table in Azure mobile service. When I try to read from it, I want it to check if a record matching my user id exists. If it does, return that else create, insert and return the newly generated record. *I am using server side scripts to do this)

Now, when doing this, the table initially has no schema, so I had to actually call a dummy insert and truncate the table to make the schema. Is there a way to manually create the schema instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not at this moment - the dummy insert + delete (or truncate, as you're doing) is the simplest way to set up the schema for the table. If you feel this is an important feature, you should create an issue (or vote for one if it already exists) on the [UserVoice forum for Azure Mobile Services](http://mobileservices.uservoice.com).